# Update in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, crud

Sorry for the question, I'm learning Asp.net with EF and I'm having problems to do a specific update.

I want to do a system that has transactions between accounts. The structural part is ok, but the problem is the following:

When the update is executed, the system makes the transfer normally, in other words, both accounts has $100, I do a transaction of $10, so one account stays $110 and another with $90.

But in the second transfer, one account stays with $80 and another with $100.

Here's the code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult TransferCurrency(Usuario usuario, ViewModelTransfer viewModel)
{
    if (usuario.Id == 0)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    if (viewModel.ForId == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }


    var usuarioTransaction = _context.Usuario.Single(c => c.NConta == viewModel.ForId);
    usuarioTransaction.Currency = usuario.Currency + viewModel.Transfer;


    var usuarioInDb = _context.Usuario.Single(m => m.Id == usuario.Id);
    usuarioInDb.Currency = usuario.Currency - viewModel.Transfer;

    _context.SaveChanges();


    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Does anybody knows what am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Your example is a little hard to follow since it isn't fully in "English" so I'm not entirely sure what your example is attempting to do.  It appears to be looking up one account and adding to it the amount of the transfer and then attempting to decrement from the other.   Since this works once, my guess is that your long running context is causing your issue.  When do you initialize the db context?   In the controller's constructor?   I would recommend moving that db context initialization into this method and see if it fixes your issue.